# How to load external html content into a div inside a page using jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

A part of mark up for the current page.

```
<div class="que-plc">
  <div class = "questionHolder">
   <div class = "questionBorder">
    <h3>A question?</h3>
    <div>
      <div ><a id="goto-que1" class="to-next-que">NEXT</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

The mark up that has to be loaded into the current page:

```
  HTML -- que1.html:

    <div class = "questionHolder"> 
      <div class = "questionBorder">
      <h3>Question Here?</h3>
        <div data-type="horizontal">
          <div><a id="goto-que2" data-role="button" class="to-next-que">NEXT</a></div>
        </div>  
      </div>
    </div>

HTML -- que2.html:

    <div class = "questionHolder"> 
      <div class = "questionBorder">
      <h3>Question Here?</h3>
        <div data-type="horizontal">
          <div><a id="goto-que3" data-role="button" class="to-next-que">NEXT</a></div>
        </div>  
      </div>
    </div>
```

The javascript to load que1.html and que2.html:

```
    $("a.to-next-que").click(function(){
    alert(this.id)
    var cur_id = this.id.toString();
    $(".questionHolder").remove();
    var last = cur_id.length
    cur_id = cur_id[last - 1];
    $.get('level/level1/que'+cur_id+'.html',function(question) {
        $('.que-plc').html(question).trigger('create');
    });
});
```

The problem is after `que1.html` is loaded into the dom i,e inside the .`que-plc` container, then the successive clicks wont load `que2.html, que3.html ... to the dom`. What is happening?

I am using `jquery-mobile 1.0.1`, so using $.mobile.loadPage, $.mobile.changePage results in a error.

And also navigating from `page1.html to page2.html` via `a link whose data-ajax="false"` wont load the javascript that is in `page2.html`

That is:

```
<body>
<div data-role="page">
</div>
<script src="play.js"></script>
```

The play.js`wont be available in`page2.html`. How can this be corrected?

Comment: place `<script src="play.js"></script>` inside `<div data-role="page">`.

Comment: Tried that too but it is not working

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

```
$('#div_content').load("page.html");
```

Load page when click button

```
$('#button').click(function(){   
    $('#div_content').load('html.page');
 });
```